# How can I export/extract a react component with css styles as a standalone snippet?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I want to export a section from my Gatsby site as a standalone html component with css styles (from styled-components) so it can be inserted into a blog as a snippet. Is this even possible in an automatic way, or am I forced to `Inspect Element -> copy HTML -> manually write/copy all the compiled classes and styles of each html block`?

I was hoping there is a faster way to do this and if not, there should be.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after searching for a solution I found the chrome extension [CSS Used](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-used/cdopjfddjlonogibjahpnmjpoangjfff/related) which allows me to copy all the css (with selectors and responsive styles) of the element and it's children. So I just had to copy all the html from the element I want to have as a snippet and copy the styles from the extension into a  tag.